# Creating a cmd line shortcut

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7

I am completely new to Windows, as i am an OSX user.

I am having to run a task in the cmd line every day, is there any way i can create a shortcut on my desktop which automates this?

Task example, open cmd, then execute:

```
atomInstaller npm -view -Xmx8g -Xms3g
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a shortcut to cmd.exe and add command line switches:

https://superuser.com/questions/358565/adding-command-line-switches-to-windows-shortcuts

Or you can put commands into a batch file using notepad ( or a better text editor ):

```
@echo off
atomInstaller npm -view -Xmx8g -Xms3g
```

save it as npm.bat then double-click it..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shortcutjs.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat):

```
call shortcutjs.bat -linkfile "%userprofile%\desktop\atominstaller.lnk" -target "C:\atomInstaller.bat" -adminpermissions yes -iconlocation "C:\Windows\System32\compstui.dll,3" -hotkey "Ctrl+Shift+M"
```

Here's the usage:

```
shortcutjs.bat -linkfile link -target target [-linkarguments linkarguments]   [-description description] [-iconlocation iconlocation] [-hotkey hotkey]  [-windowstyle 1|3|7] [-workingdirectory workingdirectory] [-adminpermissions yes|no]
```

You can add additional parameter with `-linkarguments` or start location with `-workingdirectory`